# Button switches app page from mainpage to page 1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm making a web browser app. I need to page 1(settings) to open when button2 is clicked and the main page (browser+search bar etc.) to close.

Will the back button go back to the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate between [PhoneApplicationPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)s using the [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

As a quick example:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/page1.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

And yes, the back button on the phone will move back through the applications page history.